# N+1 Query how to use includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

If I have a n+1 query problem, but none of the models have a controller, I just use the association to get what I want. What can I do.

DB schema:

`Project belongs_to domain`
 `Domain has_many projects`

`Domain has_many domain_datas`
 `Domain_datas belongs_to domain`

`Domain_datas` has a column called `index` so in order to get the `index` I do this in a view:

```
project.domain.domain_datas.index
```

Comment: Can you describe the schema, what you are trying to get, and the situation a bit more? If this is a Rails app, how are you working without controllers?

Comment: post your view where you are using domain and domain.domain_datas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should get you all of those models fully pre-loaded:

```
 Project.includes(domain: {domain_datas: :index})
```

Also see "13.1 Eager Loading Multiple Associations" on: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: Why do you have n+1? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your problem. The code I posted should use a single db query to load all objects into memory (you should be able to see this if you run it in the console). That reduces your n+1 query problem to 1. I assumed it was the number of queries you were trying to reduce, what is it?